# Mouse pointer issue

Tags: mouse, cursor, shadow

I am facing problem with mouse pointer/cursor. whenever I am moving mouse I am getting this unwanted animation. I have not enabled this on purpose. Please help me with this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPuUS.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post Ubuntu release/version and hardware specifications, particularly the graphics.

Answer (score -1):

My issue got solved. I had mistakenly enabled zoom option. After turning it off the trail got dissapes